# Can I write to the folder of an application that is not mine (data / data / com.glob.etc) -java(android)?

Tags: java, android, file

I need to create a folder and a file within a folder of an application that is not what I'm using, since I'm creating an application.

I have used this way, but not if it does not create or do not have permissions:

Just let me know if there is any way to create folders and files in data / data / com.glob.etc without this folder of my application.

```
File folder = new File("/data/data/com.glob.etc/example_folder");

folder.mkdir();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Java applications can create folders and files into folders which is not the folder of the application.

But of course this will only succeed if the OS user that runs the Java application has the permission to create those folders and files.

Your code looks fine. One thing to note that `File.mkdir()` can only be used to create a child folder of an *already existing* folder. If you want to create a full path (meaning all folders that don't exist in the path), use `File.mkdirs()` instead.

`File.mkdirs()` is more flexible in the way that it also works if only the last element is to be created, so you should prefer to use that.

**Edit:**

Since you mentioned this is an Android project: Yes, this also works on Android, but you'll also have to request permission for this. In the manifest you have to add something like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: But I need to create a folder in data / data / glob.etc (application folder that is not mine), this could be done ? In android

Comment: Android is a key information, you should've mentioned it in the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm new on this page. But could be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Edited my answer.

Comment: I already had this permission, but still not working. I need to do is create a folder within a folder outside of my application. Do not know if I explained well